# VBScript loop advice

Tags: loops, vbscript

```vb
sqlRows = rst.GetRows()
i = 0

For Each element In sqlRows
    If i > 0 And i < sizeOfState + 1 Then 
        SmartTags("visu_state_on")(i - 1) = element
    ElseIf i > sizeOfState And i < 2 * sizeOfState + 1 Then
        SmartTags("visu_state_off")(i - sizeOfState - 1) = element
    ElseIf i > (2 * sizeOfState ) And i < 2 * sizeOfState + sizeOfMeasurement + 1 Then
        SmartTags("visu_limits_right")(i - (2 * sizeOfState - 1)) = element
    ElseIf i > 2 * sizeOfState + sizeOfMeasurement And i < 2 * (sizeOfStanja + sizeOfMeasurement ) + 1 Then
        SmartTags("visu_limits_left")(i - (2 * sizeOfState + sizeOfMeasurement )) = element
    End If

    i = i + 1
Next
```

With code above I'm looping through array `sqlRows` and with variable `i` I'm filling other four arrays with data from `sqlRows`.

This solution works but I'm wondering is there more elegant way to achieve the same.

- sqlRows is array with dimensions 343x1,
- visu_state_on is array with dimensions 8x1,
- visu_state_off is array with dimensions 8x1,
- visu_limits_right is array with dimensions 160x1,
- visu_limits_left is array with dimensions 160x1,

and variables `sizeOfState` and `sizeOfMeasurement` are just there that I can calculate indexes for these four arrays.

Comment: *if it ain’t broke, don’t fix it*, or specify your criteria of elegance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing you can remove the first clause from each of your conditions, because they will always be true

- `i` starts with the value 0 and is always incremented, so the value will never be less than zero.
- If a value is not less than `n + 1` (condition in previous `ElseIf`) then it's guaranteed to be greater than `n`.

Also, VBScript does have a `<=` comparison operator, so it's better to compare  `i <= n` rather than `i < n + 1`.

I would also recommend calculating values that won't change inside the loop just once outside the loop. Re-calculating them with each loop cycle is a waste of resources.

Adding an `Else` branch to handle values greater than `2 * (sizeOfStanja + sizeOfMeasurement)` might be a good idea too.

```
sqlRows = rst.GetRows()
i = 0

ref1 = 2 * sizeOfState
ref2 = ref1 + sizeOfMeasurement
ref3 = 2 * (sizeOfStanja + sizeOfMeasurement)

For Each element In sqlRows
  If i <= sizeOfState Then 
    SmartTags("visu_state_on")(i - 1) = element
  ElseIf i <= ref1 Then
    SmartTags("visu_state_off")(i - sizeOfState - 1) = element
  ElseIf i <= ref2 Then
    SmartTags("visu_limits_right")(i - ref1 + 1) = element
  ElseIf i <= ref3 Then
    SmartTags("visu_limits_left")(i - ref2) = element
  Else
    'handle i > ref3 here
  End If

  i = i + 1
Next
```